# joomla routing in cmgroupbuing component

Tags: joomla

How can I change cmgroupbuying **joomla** URL in component router file?

For example I have a Deal width this address

> index.php/component/cmgroupbuying/deal/5/aaaaa?Itemid=437

replace
with

> index.php/deal/5

Right now I'm trying change `route.php` file in component but this not right

Answer (score 0):

You have 2 options.

**1:**
Create a custom system plugin which is listening to the `onAfterRoute` and `onAfterInitialise` event, to add `buildroules` and to preprocess the request url, so that the »cmgroupbuying« component will be triggered with the right variables like:

```
$vars = [
    'option' => 'com_cmgroupbuying',
    'view' => …
];
```

All in all this can become a quite complicated thing, since you have to find a generic way to do transform the url in both ways (url to variables and vice versa), what should be done by registering additional `router rules`. If you decide to do so, have a look at the »language filter« plugin or [here](https://docs.joomla.org/J2.5:Creating_a_System_Plugin_to_augment_JRouter), because therein a similar thing is done.

In a nutshell, your plugin must act if either: `JRoute::_( … )` is called, to make the transformation you desire (variables to url). And `onAfterRoute` to do the opposite (url to variables).

That is basically what a component router does and if `com_cmgroupbuying` is not your own, you cannot/should not create/modify this and take the »route over a plugin« instead.

**2:**
Create a menu link for each deal/item. This is the easiest way, but not generic, depending on how many links you need to create, or to maintain, this the fastest thing to do.

**UPDATE**

For me routing in Joomla! is the most complicated and misleading thing in the whole system and good documentation is rare. One needs a good understanding of the overall application flow, how the used component is figured out and instantiated.
Additionally you need to understand the routing concept in Joomla!, what is different from most other Frameworks like symfony or drupal, where a url like `/way/to/go/{id}` is mapped to a controller method. Joomla! is working like a command-line application and »SEF« (search engine friendly) URLS are lying in a layer above that. With a url like `/way/to/go/{id}` two things need to be done:

1. Transform the array of Segments (numerical index based array) `['way', 'to', 'go', <id>]` into a set of arguments (most often called vars, associative array) `[ 'option' => 'com_…', 'view' => 'viewtoshow', 'task' => 'thingToDo', … ]`. That is what the `parse` method needs to return to the Joomla! system, which will use those »vars«/arguments to execute the component.
2. Transform the set of »vars«/arguments (associative array) to the url segments (numerical indexed array), what basically is the opposite of 1. But this transformation is executed each time `JRoute::_()` is executed. If it is called like `JRoute::_('index.php?option=com_somecome&view=someview')`, Joomla! will use the Router of `com_somecome` and call its `build` method and hand over the arguments from the string given to `JRoute::_(<string>)`

But keep in mind that going from 1. to 2. and from 2. to 1. needs to keep up an invariance, what means the set of `vars` and the connected `url` need to be distinct, and going from an A to B must always be reversible and lead to the same result all the time.

How this transformation is done, is totally dependent from your component and if you would like to »short-circuit« joomla, so that `/deal/{id}` goes over to `['option' => 'com_cmgroupbuying', 'view' => 'product', …]` you will **need a system plugin and set the missing vars** `onAfterInitialise`, otherwise your component will never be called.

More detailed documentation can be found [here](https://docs.joomla.org/Supporting_SEF_URLs_in_your_component)

I want to underline the recommendation **to look into the source** as mentioned above.

Comment: I Have This router in cmgroup buing  . i dont know How it works?

Answer (score 0):

function CMGroupBuyingBuildRoute(&$query)
{
    $segments = array();

```
if(isset($query['view']))
{
    if($query['view'] == 'dealprevue' || $query['view'] == 'freecouponprevue'
            || $query['view'] == 'todaydeal' || $query['view'] == 'todayfreecoupon'
            || $query['view'] == 'cart' || $query['view'] == 'checkout' || $query['view'] == 'orders'
            || $query['view'] == 'alldeals' || $query['view'] == 'freecoupons'
            || $query['view'] == 'activedeals' || $query['view'] == 'activefreecoupons'
            || $query['view'] == 'upcomingdeals' || $query['view'] == 'upcomingfreecoupons'
            || $query['view'] == 'expireddeals' || $query['view'] == 'expiredfreecoupons'
            || $query['view'] == 'partner' || $query['view'] == 'dealmanagement'
            || $query['view'] == 'freecouponmanagement'|| $query['view'] == 'products')
    {
        unset($query['view']);
    }
    elseif($query['view'] == 'deal' || $query['view'] == 'freecoupon'
            || $query['view'] == 'order' || $query['view'] == 'rssfeeds'
            || $query['view'] == 'search' || $query['view'] == 'dealsubmission'
            || $query['view'] == 'partnermanagement'
            || $query['view'] == 'staffmanagement'
            || $query['view'] == 'freecouponsubmission'
            || $query['view'] == 'category'
            || $query['view'] == 'coupon'
            || $query['view'] == 'product')
    {
        $segments[] = $query['view'];
        unset($query['view']);
    }
    else
    {
        $segments[] = $query['view'];
    }

    if(isset($query['navigation']))
    {
            $segments[] = $query['navigation'];
            unset($query['navigation']);
    }

    if(isset($query['id']))
    {
            $segments[] = $query['id'];
            unset($query['id']);
    }

    if(isset($query['alias']))
    {
            $segments[] = $query['alias'];
            unset($query['alias']);
    }

    if(isset($query['download']))
    {
            $segments[] = $query['download'];
            unset($query['download']);
    }
}

if(isset($query['type']))
{
        $segments[] = $query['type'];
        unset($query['type']);
}

if(isset($query['location']))
{
        $segments[] = $query['location'];
        unset($query['location']);
}

return $segments;
```

}

Answer (score 0):

function CMGroupBuyingParseRoute($segments)
{
    $vars = array();

```
switch($segments[0])
{
    case 'deal':
        $vars['view'] = 'deal';
        if(isset($segments[1]))
            $vars['id'] = $segments[1];
        if(isset($segments[2]))
            $vars['alias'] = $segments[2];
        break;
    case 'freecoupon':
        $vars['view'] = 'freecoupon';
        if(isset($segments[1]))
            $vars['id'] = $segments[1];
        if(isset($segments[2]))
            $vars['alias'] = $segments[2];
        break;
    case 'order':
        $vars['view'] = 'order';
        if(isset($segments[1]))
            $vars['id'] = $segments[1];
        break;
    case 'todaydeal':
        $vars['view'] = 'todaydeal';
        break;
    case 'todayfreecoupon':
        $vars['view'] = 'todayfreecoupon';
        break;
    case 'freecoupons':
        $vars['view'] = 'freecoupons';
        break;
    case 'alldeals':
        $vars['view'] = 'alldeals';
        break;
    case 'activedeals':
        $vars['view'] = 'activedeals';
        break;
    case 'upcomingdeals':
        $vars['view'] = 'upcomingdeals';
        break;
    case 'expireddeals':
        $vars['view'] = 'expireddeals';
        break;
    case 'activefreecoupons':
        $vars['view'] = 'activefreecoupons';
        break;
    case 'upcomingfreecoupons':
        $vars['view'] = 'upcomingfreecoupons';
        break;
    case 'expiredfreecoupons':
        $vars['view'] = 'expiredfreecoupons';
        break;
    case 'cart':
        $vars['view'] = 'cart';
        break;
    case 'checkout':
        $vars['view'] = 'checkout';
        break;
    case 'search':
        $vars['view'] = 'search';
        break;
    case 'orders':
        $vars['view'] = 'orders';
        break;
    case 'partner':
        $vars['view'] = 'partner';
        break;
    case 'dealmanagement':
        $vars['view'] = 'dealmanagement';
        break;
    case 'dealsubmission':
        $vars['view'] = 'dealsubmission';
        if(isset($segments[1]))
            $vars['id'] = $segments[1];
        break;
    case 'freecouponmanagement':
        $vars['view'] = 'freecouponmanagement';
        break;
    case 'freecouponsubmission':
        $vars['view'] = 'freecouponsubmission';
        if(isset($segments[1]))
            $vars['id'] = $segments[1];
        break;
    case 'rssfeeds':
        $vars['view'] = 'rssfeeds';
        if(isset($segments[1]))
            $vars['type'] = $segments[1];
        if(isset($segments[2]))
            $vars['location'] = $segments[2];
        break;
    case 'partnermanagement':
        $vars['view'] = 'partnermanagement';
        if(isset($segments[1]))
            $vars['navigation'] = $segments[1];
        if(isset($segments[2]))
            $vars['id'] = $segments[2];
        break;
    case 'staffmanagement':
        $vars['view'] = 'staffmanagement';
        if(isset($segments[1]))
            $vars['navigation'] = $segments[1];
        if(isset($segments[2]))
            $vars['id'] = $segments[2];
        break;
    case 'category':
        $vars['view'] = 'category';
        if(isset($segments[1]))
            $vars['id'] = $segments[1];
        break;
    case 'coupon':
        $vars['view'] = 'coupon';
        if(isset($segments[1]))
        {
            $vars['download'] = $segments[1];
            $vars['tmpl'] = 'component';
        }
        break;
    case 'products':
        $vars['view'] = 'products';
        break;
    case 'product':
        $vars['view'] = 'product';
        if(isset($segments[1]))
            $vars['id'] = $segments[1];
        if(isset($segments[2]))
        {
            $vars['alias'] = str_replace(':', '-', $segments[2]);
        }
        break;
    default:
        $vars['view'] = '';
        break;
}

return $vars;
```

}